# How do I load a random snippet of PHP on a page?

Tags: php

Each time a user loads a page, a one random (ie. promotional popup) code snippet is displayed. Once a code is displayed it will not display it again to a user for 24 hours.

For example, it would execute one of these snippets:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='codes/pop1.php'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='codes/pop2.php'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='codes/pop3.php'></script>
```

Comment: What happens if I load the page more times than you have popups?

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're stuck with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<?php
    $code = array();
        $code[0] = "file1.php";
        $code[1] = "file2.php";
        $code[2] = "file3.php";
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src='codes/<?php echo $code[array_rand($code)]; ?>'></script>
```

---

**Edit:**

```
<?php
    // array code here

   $shown_ad = $code[array_rand($code)];
   $day = 1000*60*60*24; // ms * sec * min * hrs
   $delay = time()+$day;
   if($shown_ad = $code[0])
   {
       set_cookie("shown_1", "shown", $delay);
   }
   // Repeat if statement for each $code[]
?>
```

Comment: Missing the "Once a code is displayed it will not display it again to a user for 24 hours." requirement.

Comment: Thanks, missed that one. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking about tracking the results to make sure ads are not repeated. Use a cookie: simplest would be a 24-hour cookie that encodes each ad, say, as one bit in the binary expansion of some long number. Now you can keep track of what ads have been shown, and it's not too difficult from there. 
This is not an ideal system (doesn't exactly track what you're trying to track) but it's a start.